# Show $F: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is diff'ble

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Hi just need a bit of help with a few parts of this practice question:

> Show $F: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ diff'ble with
>   respect to $t \in (0, \infty)$, where
>
> $$F(t) := \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-tx^2}\cos(x)dx$$

According to theorems in my text, I know I need to show 3 things:

1. $f(x,t) = e^{-tx^2}\cos(x)$ is $\mu$ integrable. I.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{-tx^2}\cos(x)|dx < \infty$

I do this by showing that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{-tx^2}\cos(x)|dx < \int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{-x^2}|dx < \infty$, by direct integration.

2. I need to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) = -x^2\cos(x)e^{-tx^2} $ exists for almost all of $x$ and is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

This certainly seems continuous for $t \in (0, \infty)$ and seems to exist for all of $x$, so I am a bit confused about how to show that this exists for 'almost' all of $x$.

3. Finally, I need to find a dominating function $h \in \mathcal{L}^1(x)$ such that   $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)| \le h(x)$

But I'm not quite sure how to construct $h(x)$ independent of $t$ to achieve this final requirement.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean assignment question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function, as you can see for $t \to 0$.

But the point is that differentiability is a **local property**. Hence, it suffices for each interval $(t_0,t_1)$ with $0<t_0<t_1$ to find a dominating function which is independent of $t$ (but only needs to hold for $t$ in the above interval).

This is easy to do, namely $x^2 e^{-t_0 x^2}$ will do.

Comment: Ahh right, thanks so much. Is my understanding of part 2 correct? I mean the partial derivative seems to exist for all $x$, so the 'almost all $x$ requirement is trivially satisfied right?

Comment: @JackReacher: Yes , indeed. You should try to remember this "local independence of $t$" trick. It appears quite often in connection to applying your theorem.